# javascript for function - How do i include another condition in the for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = 'First JavaScript string.';
    var c = 'This is second text.'
    var colors = new Array("#FF0000","#000000");
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    document.write("<span style=\"color:" + colors[(i % colors.length)] + ";\">" + s[i] + "</span>");
</script>
```

How do i include 'c' string in the for loop?

Comment: what do you want to do with `c` string in the loop, please explain a bit.

Comment: What do you want to do with that c string? append it to span text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put single statements in the for loop, you can have how ever many as you want, as long as the centre expression evaluates to a truthy value:

Some examples:

Multiple declarations and a bigger condition:

```
for(var i = 0, z = 0; i < 100 && z < 100; z++, i++){
    console.log(i, z)
}
```

No incrementation and no declaration:

```
var i = 0; 
for(;i < 100;){
   i++;
   console.log(i)
}
```

For your situation I think you want this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < s.length && i < c.length; i++){
    //...do something here 
}
```

This will stop when I is bigger then the length of `s` or the length of `c`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to use a nested loop, although you need to be more specific.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = 'First JavaScript string.';
    var c = 'This is second text.'
    var colors = new Array("#FF0000","#000000");
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        for (var m = 0; m < c.length; m++) {
            ... print something in here
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition should be false, when `i` is greater/equal to summarized length of `s` and `c`.

If `i` is smaller than length of `s`, you should write `s[i]` (with marking), else - write `c[i-s.length]`. I'd say that ternary operator would fit great here.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0, var j = 0; i < s.length; i++, j--) {
   ;
}
```